# incluir campo de texto (textfield) java

Tags: java

Quero adicionar [este *text field*](http://www.fredosaurus.com/notes-java/GUI/components/40textarea/25ex-textarea.html) no meu jogo.
Ja alterei o código no meu jogo mas esse *text field* está a ser aberto numa nova janela, mas eu quero que esse *text field* esteja incluído na própria janela do jogo.

Logo em baixo do botão "definiçoes".

Este é o meu jogo:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Vector;
import java.util.List;
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.net.*;
import java.applet.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class MemoryGame extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    ClassLoader cl = null;
    Font f; 
    TextField msg1, msg2, password,t;
    String s;
    Label mostra;           
    public int delay = 1000; //1000 milliseconds

    public void Contador()
    {
    ActionListener counter = new ActionListener() 
    {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
        tempo++;
        TempoScore.setText("Tempo: " + tempo);
            }
    };
    new Timer(delay, counter).start();
    }

    public void updateHitMiss() 
    {
        HitScore.setText("Acertou: " + Hit);
        MissScore.setText("Falhou: " + Miss);
    PontosScore.setText("Pontos: " + Pontos);
    }

    private JFrame window = new JFrame("Jogo da Memoria");
    private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 500; // pixels
    private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 500; // pixels
    private JButton exitBtn, baralharBtn, solveBtn, restartBtn, maximoBtn, definicoesBtn;
    ImageIcon ButtonIcon = createImageIcon("card1.png"); //.jpg 
    private JButton[] gameBtn = new JButton[16];
    private ArrayList<Integer> gameList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    //List<Integer> lista = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
    private int Hit, Miss, Pontos, Maximo;
    public int tempo = 0;   
    private int counter = 0;
    private int[] btnID = new int[2];
    private int[] btnValue = new int[2];
    private JLabel HitScore, MissScore, TempoScore, PontosScore, MaximoScore;
    private JPanel gamePnl = new JPanel();
    private JPanel buttonPnl = new JPanel();
    private JPanel scorePnl = new JPanel();
    private JTextArea _resultArea = new JTextArea(6, 20);

    protected static ImageIcon createImageIcon(String path) 
    {
        java.net.URL imgURL = MemoryGame.class.getResource(path);
        if (imgURL != null) 
    {
            return new ImageIcon(imgURL);
        } 
    else  return null;
    }

    public MemoryGame()
    {
        createGUI();
        createJPanels();
        setArrayListText();
        window.setTitle("Jogo da Memoria");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        window.setVisible(true);
        Contador();

        //... Set textarea's initial text, scrolling, and border.
        _resultArea.setText("\n");
        JScrollPane scrollingArea = new JScrollPane(_resultArea);

        //... Get the content pane, set layout, add to center
        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        content.add(scrollingArea, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //... Set window characteristics.
        this.setContentPane(content);
        //this.setTitle("TextAreaDemo B");
        //this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
    }

    public void createGUI()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
        {
            gameBtn[i] = new JButton(ButtonIcon);
            gameBtn[i].addActionListener(this);
        }
        HitScore = new JLabel("Acertou: " + Hit);
        MissScore = new JLabel("Falhou: " + Miss);
    TempoScore = new JLabel("Tempo: " + tempo);
    PontosScore = new JLabel("Pontos: " + Pontos);  
        exitBtn = new JButton("Sair");
        exitBtn.addActionListener(this);
        baralharBtn = new JButton("Baralhar");
        baralharBtn.addActionListener(this);
        solveBtn = new JButton("Resolver");
        solveBtn.addActionListener(this);
    restartBtn = new JButton("Recomecar");
        restartBtn.addActionListener(this);
    maximoBtn = new JButton("Pontuacoes");
        maximoBtn.addActionListener(this);
    definicoesBtn = new JButton("Definicoes");
        definicoesBtn.addActionListener(this);

        //... Set textarea's initial text, scrolling, and border.
        _resultArea.setText("\n");
        JScrollPane scrollingArea = new JScrollPane(_resultArea);

        //... Get the content pane, set layout, add to center
        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        content.add(scrollingArea, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //... Set window characteristics.
        this.setContentPane(content);
        //this.setTitle("TextAreaDemo B");
        //this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
    }

    public void createJPanels()
    {
        gamePnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
        for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
        {
            gamePnl.add(gameBtn[i]);
        }
        buttonPnl.add(baralharBtn);
        buttonPnl.add(exitBtn);
        buttonPnl.add(solveBtn);
    buttonPnl.add(restartBtn);
    buttonPnl.add(maximoBtn);
    buttonPnl.add(definicoesBtn);
        buttonPnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        scorePnl.add(HitScore);
        scorePnl.add(MissScore);
    scorePnl.add(TempoScore);
    scorePnl.add(PontosScore);
        scorePnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 0));
        window.add(scorePnl, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        window.add(gamePnl, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        window.add(buttonPnl, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    }

    public void setArrayListText() // gera numeros aleatorios
    { 
    List<Integer> lista = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
    Collections.shuffle(lista);
    gameList.addAll(lista);
    }

    public boolean sameValues()
    {
        if (btnValue[0] == btnValue[1])
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void pass() 
    {
        s = "123";
        msg1 = new TextField("Digite a password:"); msg1.setEditable(false);
        password = new TextField(12); password.setEchoCharacter('*');
        msg2 = new TextField(30); msg2.setEditable(false);
        add(msg1); add(password); add(msg2);
    }
    /*
    public boolean action(Event e, Object o) 
    {
            if (e.target instanceof TextField)
            if (e.target ==password)
            if (e.arg.equals(s)) msg2.setText("Acesso permitido");
            else msg2.setText("Password invalida.");
            return true;
    } */
    /*
    class EscutaJanela extends WindowAdapter
    {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) 
            setVisible(true);
            dispose();
    }
    */

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if (exitBtn == e.getSource())
        {
            System.exit(0);
        }

        if (baralharBtn == e.getSource())
        {
            List<Integer> lista = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
            Collections.shuffle(lista);
            gameList.addAll(lista);
        }

        if (solveBtn == e.getSource())
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
            {   // enable false, ao clicar, não modifica o aspecto(cor) da quadricula,
        gameBtn[i].setEnabled(false); // enabled false-> cor cinzenta(padrão de fundo), true azul                
        gameBtn[i].setVisible(true); // visible true-> fica nºs visiveis
                gameBtn[i].setText("" + gameList.get(i));       
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
        {           
            if (gameBtn[i] == e.getSource())
            {
                gameBtn[i].setText("" + gameList.get(i));
                gameBtn[i].setEnabled(false);
                counter++;

        if(Hit==7)
        {
                    if (counter == 2)
                    {
            gameBtn[btnID[0]].setEnabled(false);
            gameBtn[btnID[1]].setEnabled(false);
            gameBtn[btnID[0]].setVisible(false);
            gameBtn[btnID[1]].setVisible(false);
            Hit = Hit +1;
            Pontos = Pontos + 25;
                    }                   
        }

        if(Hit==8)
        {  
                    int PontuacaoMax=0;
                    PontuacaoMax=Pontos;
                    window = new JFrame(" FIM DO JOGO ");           
                    JLabel label3 = new JLabel("\n PARABENS FINALIZOU O JOGO ! TOTAL DE PONTOS: "+PontuacaoMax);    
                    int[] anArray;
                    int w=0;
                    int h=1;
                    anArray = new int[20];
                    anArray[w] = PontuacaoMax;  
                    System.out.printf("Jogo %d,",h);
                    System.out.println(" Pontuacao final : "+PontuacaoMax);
                    w++;h++;
                    window.add("Center", label3);               
                    window.show();                      
                    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bruno.azevedo8\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Jogo_Memoria\\resources\\fogo.jpg");
                    JLabel label = new JLabel(img);
                    window.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                    window.pack();  
                    window.setVisible(true); 
                    gameBtn[btnID[0]].setEnabled(false);
                    gameBtn[btnID[1]].setEnabled(false);
                    gameBtn[btnID[0]].setVisible(true);
                    gameBtn[btnID[1]].setVisible(true);
                    cl = getClass().getClassLoader();
                    //AudioClip audio = Applet.newAudioClip(cl.getResource("C:\\Users\\bruno.azevedo8\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Memoria\\Jogo_Memoria\\resources\\bottle-open.wav"));
                    //audio.play();                 
                }

                if (counter == 3)
                {               
                    if (sameValues())
                    {
                        gameBtn[btnID[0]].setEnabled(false);
                        gameBtn[btnID[1]].setEnabled(false);
                        gameBtn[btnID[0]].setVisible(true);
                        gameBtn[btnID[1]].setVisible(true);
                        Hit = Hit +1;
                        Pontos = Pontos + 25;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        gameBtn[btnID[0]].setEnabled(true);
                        gameBtn[btnID[0]].setText("");
                        gameBtn[btnID[1]].setEnabled(true);
                        gameBtn[btnID[1]].setText("");
                        Miss = Miss +1;
                        Pontos = Pontos - 5;                       
                    }
                    counter = 1; 
                }
                /*if (Pontos <= 0)
                {
                        Pontos=0;
                } */
                if (counter == 1) // na grelha identifica o 1º clique do rato
                {
                    btnID[0] = i;
                    btnValue[0] = gameList.get(i);
                }
                if (counter == 2) // na grelha identifica o 2º clique do rato(diferente do 1º)
                {
                    btnID[1] = i;
                    btnValue[1] = gameList.get(i);
                }
            }
        }

    if (restartBtn == e.getSource()) // apaga a grelha
        { 
            Hit=0;
            Miss=0;
            tempo=-1;
            Pontos=0;
            for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
            {
                gameBtn[i].setText("");
                gameBtn[i].setEnabled(true);
                gameBtn[i].setVisible(true);    
            }
        }  

    if (maximoBtn == e.getSource()) //mostra melhor pontucao
        {
            window = new JFrame(" Jogo da Memoria - Melhores Pontuacoes:"); 
            int Max=0,PontuacaoMax=0;           

            //private static int maxValue(char[] chars) 
            //{
                //int  = chars[0]; 
                /*
                int[] anArray;
                anArray = new int[20];
                for (int w = 0; w < anArray.length; w++) 
                {
                    if (anArray[w]>= Max) 
                    {
                        Max = anArray[w];
                        JLabel label2 = new JLabel(" Pontuacao Maxima: "+Max);
                        window.add("Center", label2);
                    }
                }

                System.out.println(PontuacaoMax);
                JLabel label5 = new JLabel(" Pontuacao: " +PontuacaoMax );
                window.add("Center", label5); */
                //return Pontos;
            //}
            /*
            anArray[w]=0;
            int w;
            for(w=0;w<20;w++)
            {
                if (anArray[w]>=PontuacaoMax)
                {
                    PontuacaoMax=anArray[w];
                    JLabel label2 = new JLabel(" Pontuacao Maxima: "+PontuacaoMax);
                    window.add("Center", label2);
                }
            } 
            */ 
            if (Pontos >= PontuacaoMax)
            {
                PontuacaoMax = Pontos;
                JLabel label2 = new JLabel(" Pontuacao Maxima: "+PontuacaoMax); 
                //Vector<Integer> v = new Vector<>();
                //v.add(PontuacaoMax);System.out.println(PontuacaoMax);
                window.add("Center", label2);
            }
            if (Pontos < PontuacaoMax)
            {
                PontuacaoMax = Pontos;
                JLabel label2 = new JLabel(" Pontuacao Maxima: 0");         
                window.add("Center", label2);
            }    

            window.show();                      
            ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bruno.azevedo8\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Jogo_Memoria\\resources\\trofeu.jpg");         
            JLabel label = new JLabel(img); 
            window.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            window.pack();  
            window.setVisible(true); 
        }

    if (definicoesBtn == e.getSource()) //mostra as definicoes
        { /*
            window = new JFrame(" Jogo da Memoria - Password:");
            window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());   
            // pass(); 
            s = "123";
            msg1 = new TextField("Digite a password:"); 
            msg1.setEditable(false);
            password = new TextField(12); 
            password.setEchoCharacter('*');
            msg2 = new TextField(30); 
            msg2.setEditable(false);
            add(msg1); 
            add(password); 
            add(msg2); 

            window.resize(300,300);
            window.show();                      
            window.pack();  
            window.setVisible(true);    
            //action(e,o);  */      

            definicoesBtn.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
            {    
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evento)
                {    
                    window = new JFrame(" Jogo da Memoria - Definicoes:");              
                    JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Escolha Nivel Dificuldade:");           
                    window.add("West", label3);                                     
                    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\bruno.azevedo8\\Documents\\NetBeansProjects\\Jogo_Memoria\\resources\\definicoes.jpg");
                    JLabel label = new JLabel(img); 
                    window.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
                    JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1));
                    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
                    JRadioButton aRadioButton = new JRadioButton(" Facil ");
                    JRadioButton bRadioButton = new JRadioButton(" Medio ");
                    JRadioButton cRadioButton = new JRadioButton(" Dificil ");

                    ChangeListener changeListener = new ChangeListener() 
                    {
                        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent changEvent) 
                        {
                            AbstractButton aButton = (AbstractButton)changEvent.getSource();
                            ButtonModel aModel = aButton.getModel();
                            boolean armed = aModel.isArmed();
                            boolean pressed = aModel.isPressed();
                            boolean selected = aModel.isSelected();

                            aRadioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                            {
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                                {                           
                                    gamePnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4));
                                    //System.out.println("4x4");
                                }
                            });
                            bRadioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                            {
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                                {                                       
                                    JButton[] gameBtn = new JButton[18];

                                     for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
                                    {
                                        gameBtn[i] = new JButton(ButtonIcon);
                                        gameBtn[i].addActionListener(this);
                                    } 

                                    gamePnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(6, 6)); /*
                                    for (int i = 0; i < gameBtn.length; i++)
                                    {
                                            gamePnl.add(gameBtn[i]);
                                    }           */                                                  
                                }
                            });
                            cRadioButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
                            {
                                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                                {                                                                                   
                                    gamePnl.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 5));                                                
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    };
                    panel.add(aRadioButton);
                    group.add(aRadioButton);
                    panel.add(bRadioButton);
                    group.add(bRadioButton);
                    panel.add(cRadioButton);
                    group.add(cRadioButton);
                    aRadioButton.addChangeListener(changeListener);
                    bRadioButton.addChangeListener(changeListener);
                    cRadioButton.addChangeListener(changeListener);
                    window.add(panel);                      
                    window.pack();  
                    window.setVisible(true); 
                }    
            });             
        }
        updateHitMiss();
    }

    public static void main(String[] argv)
    {      
        JFrame win = new MemoryGame();
        win.setVisible(true);
        //new MemoryGame(); */
        try 
        {
            // criação do socket TCP de ligação ao servidor, o 1º argumento
            // é o nome da máquina, o 2º é o número do porto
            Socket sd = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName(argv[0]), (new Integer(argv[1])).intValue());
            // obtenção dos canais de leitura e escrita do socket
            InputStream in = sd.getInputStream();
            OutputStream out = sd.getOutputStream();
            // criação do buffer para envio e recepção de informação
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            for (;;) 
            {
                // pede a mensagem ao utilizador
                System.out.print("Introduza a mensagem: ");
                System.out.flush();
                int length = System.in.read(buffer);
                // envia ao servidor o buffer através do outputstream
                out.write(buffer, 0, length);
                out.flush();
                // se premiu return, fecho da ligação
                if (length == 1) break;
                // leitura da mensagem ecoada pelo servidor
                length = in.read(buffer);
                System.out.println(new String(buffer,0,0,length));
            }
        } 
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
                // Surgiu algum problema com a ligação ao socket
                System.out.println(e.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("ligação fechada");

    }
}
```

Alterei no meu jogo as seguintes linhas: de forma a incluir o textfield .

```
public MemoryGame()
    {
        createGUI();
        createJPanels();
        setArrayListText();
        window.setTitle("Jogo da Memoria");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        window.setVisible(true);
        Contador();
        //novo codigo textfield
        //... Set textarea's initial text, scrolling, and border.
        _resultArea.setText("\n");
        JScrollPane scrollingArea = new JScrollPane(_resultArea);

        //... Get the content pane, set layout, add to center
        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        content.add(scrollingArea, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        //... Set window characteristics.
        this.setContentPane(content);
        //this.setTitle("TextAreaDemo B");
        //this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.pack();
//fim novo codigo text field
    }
```

O que esta em fundo cinzento.

Antes disso inclui esta linha :72: 
private JTextArea _resultArea = new JTextArea(6, 20);

Tambem inclui mais duas linhas ao meu jogo:

```
public static void main(String[] argv)
    {      
        JFrame win = new MemoryGame();  // nova linha
        win.setVisible(true);           // nova linha
        //new MemoryGame(); */
       //... resto do codigo
     }
```

De resto ficou tudo igual, portanto não quero abrir o textfield numa nova janela.
Mas abrir juntamente com o jogo da memoria, o textfield deverá ficar em baixo do Botão definições ou pelo menos aparecer nessa janela, depois disso eu tento por no sitio.

Já perdi uma tarde inteira com o text field e não consigo de modo nenhum meter o text field na janela do jogo principal.

Comment: Nossa, quanto código...

Comment: Experimente criar um [exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Já editei a pergunta, acho que ficou mais simples de entender o problema.

Comment: Tente ser mais específico, há muito código pra analisar, poucos aqui irão tentar te ajudar.